# tmux: Page Up/Down in Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, tmux

Unfortunately it seems like the normal C-b > PgUp or C-b > ctrl+arrows aren't working; instead, I'm just seeing the characters `5~` be printed whenever I C-b and then try to use PgUp. Even mouse mode scrolling (which I would prefer to avoid anyway) just prints characters to the screen instead of moving the buffer.

Is there some additional config I need to be using? I'm using mintty, tmux is launched from bash and has its default shell set to fish.

Comment: I have the same issue. The only way I've found to get around it is to use a program like autohotkey (I think that's the name of it -- my computer is at work) to send the correct key sequence and bind that to some other key sequence, like Ctrl--/Ctrl-+. It used to work but stopped for some reason, and I never went back to figure it out. It could be that I simply don't remember the correct key sequence to trigger it...

Comment: IIRC, there are three keys to munge in this manner, the one to put you into Copy-mode (I think that's what it's called), then the Page-up/Page-down keys.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I had a typo in my .tmux.conf. It needed to say `set-window-option -g mode-keys vi` but it said `set-window-option -g mode-keys vim`. Of course, I did not have any keys bound for "copy-mode-vim".

If you recently switched versions of tmux from 1.x to 2.x, the tmux.conf syntax may have changed for you as well. You'd see errors on tmux startup if that is the case.

As a reference, if you're interested, I have the following working keybindings show up when using :list-keys

Puts you into copy mode with <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd> <kbd>PgUp</kbd>

```
bind-key    -T prefix       PPage             copy-mode -u
```

Uses <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> when already in copy-mode:

```
 bind-key    -T copy-mode    NPage             send-keys -X page-down
 bind-key    -T copy-mode    PPage             send-keys -X page-up
```

Used <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> when already in copy-mode-vi

```
 bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi NPage             send-keys -X page-down
 bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi PPage             send-keys -X page-up
```

Posting the output of  `C-b :list-keys` and your the contents of your `~/.tmux.conf` would help.